# CodeIgniter 4 Model: Modify retrieved data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to use the CodeIgniter 4 Model for some basic CRUD operation on a database. Now I've come to a point where I'm planning to return the mySQL DATETIME fields as an unix timestamp. What I got so far:
**Controller:**

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers\API;

use CodeIgniter\RESTful\ResourceController;
use CodeIgniter\API\ResponseTrait;
use App\Models\ConfigModel;

class Config extends ResourceController
{
    use ResponseTrait;
    public function index()
    {
        $model = new ConfigModel();
        $default = NULL;
        if (null !== $this->request->getVar('config_default')){
            $default = filter_var($this->request->getVar('config_default'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
    }
    return $this->respond($model->getConfig($default));
}
```

**Model:**

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class ConfigModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'configuration';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $allowedFields = ['name','value','is_default'];

    protected function getCurrentConfig($item = NULL){
        if (isset($item)){
            $query = $this->query('SELECT * FROM configuration WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM configuration WHERE name = '.$this->escape($item).')');
        return $query->getResult();
        } else {
            $query = $this->query('SELECT * FROM configuration WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM configuration GROUP BY name)');
            return $query->getResult();
        }
    }

    protected function getDefaultConfig($item = NULL){
        if (isset($item)){
            return $this->where(['is_default' => 1, 'name' => $item])->findAll();
        } else {
            return $this->getWhere(['is_default' => 1])->getResult();
        }
    }

    public function getConfig($default = FALSE){
        if ($default) {
            return $this->getDefaultConfig();
        } else {
            return $this->getCurrentConfig();
        }
    }
```

**Result:**

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "ticket_number_format",
        "value": "default",
        "is_default": "1",
        "create_timestamp": "2021-09-22 09:11:07" // need: 1632294667
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "ticket_number_format_default_alphanumeric",
        "value": "true",
        "is_default": "1",
        "create_timestamp": "2021-09-22 09:21:40" // need: 1632295300
    },
    ...
]
```

I thought about manipulating the result array, but it seems to be too complex for what I'm trying to achieve. I've red about the [CodeIgniter Entities](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/entities.html), but not sure if this is the right way. Also I didn't find any possibility to alter the SQL statement for single columns with CI tools (i.e. `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(create_timestamp)`)

What would be the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out I was on the right path. The key to this issue are those entity classes from the documentation. I added following entity class:

```
<?php namespace App\Entities;

use CodeIgniter\Entity\Entity;
use CodeIgniter\I18n\Time;

class Config extends Entity
{
    public function getCreateTimestamp()
    {
        $this->attributes['create_timestamp'] = $this->mutateDate($this->attributes['create_timestamp']);
        return $this->attributes['create_timestamp']->getTimestamp();
    }
}
```

and modified the model:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class ConfigModel extends Model
{
    // ...
    // I think this is only needed for those 
    // built-in CRUD function like findAll()
    protected $returnType    = 'App\Entities\Config';

    // ...
    // Use the entity here
    return $query->getResult('App\Entities\Config');

    // ...
    // But can be omitted here
    return $this->where(['is_default' => 1, 'name' => $item])->findAll();

    // ...
}
```

Gives following result:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "ticket_number_format",
        "value": "default",
        "is_default": "1",
        "create_timestamp": 1632319867
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "ticket_number_format_default_alphanumeric",
        "value": "true",
        "is_default": "1",
        "create_timestamp": 1632320500
    },
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use filter
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/filters.html

```
class MyFilter implements FilterInterface
{
    public function before(RequestInterface $request, $arguments = null)
    {
        // Do something here
    }

    public function after(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $arguments = null)
    {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```